# Enumeration in SAS

Tags: sas, enumeration

I want to enumerate over groups in SAS. I have the following data set and have attached 2 possible scenarios that I am looking for.
locationnurseunitcodedesc   transaction_start_dt_tm transaction_stop_dt_tm  THIS IS WHAT I WANT BETTER YET

```
STATION 1   8/31/16 10:33   10/3/16 9:54    1   1
STATION 2   10/3/16 9:54    10/3/16 9:54    1   1
STATION 3   10/3/16 9:54    10/3/16 9:54    1   0
STATION 3   10/3/16 9:54    10/3/16 9:54    2   0
STATION 3   10/3/16 9:54    10/3/16 12:11   3   1
STATION 4   10/3/16 12:11   10/3/16 18:39   1   1
STATION 3   10/3/16 18:39   10/4/16 12:26   1   0
STATION 3   10/4/16 12:26   10/13/16 10:43  2   0
STATION 3   10/13/16 10:43  10/13/16 10:43  3   0
STATION 3   10/13/16 10:43  10/4/16 12:25   4   1
```

When I use the following code the seq number never goes above 2

```
data wantONETWO;
set WANTONE;
RETAIN SEQ 0;
SEQ=1;
PRIOR_UNIT = LAG(locationnurseunitcodedesc);
IF locationnurseunitcodedesc = PRIOR_UNIT THEN DO;
SEQ + 1;
END;
run;
```

Best

Aaron

Comment: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-can-i-create-an-enumeration-variable-by-groups/

Comment: You're always setting SEQ=1 to it'll only ever increment once and then be reset back to one. You need BY processing for this not the LAG approach being used.

Comment: Please activate the green check mark if the answer solved your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your operations backwards.  Always increment , but then reset to 1 when starting a new group.  I'm not going to type your long variable name. Let's just use STATION instead.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  seq+1;
  if station ne lag(station) then seq=1 ;
run;
```

You could also use BY group processing, but since your groups are not sorted you will need the `notsorted` keyword on the `BY` statement.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by station notsorted;
  seq+1;
  if first.station then seq=1 ;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you Tom, I ran the second piece of code of yours using the By variable and it worked perfectly. Too simple of a solution after looking at it LOL. The notsorted option was the key.